# Cross domain login POST - pitfalls

Tags: php, html, post, ssl, https

We have an app hosted on our domain. All users are required to first log in through a POST form. Once login has happened, then form redirects to dashboard page on our site automatically.

Is it possible to allow some clients to host their own login forms (on their site), that POSTS to our app? Is cross-domain posting considered bad practise in any way? Are there any pitfalls to be aware of? And lastly, how is SSL taken care of given that our site always runs on HTTPS, but client sites may not? Can this be circumvented with an iframe?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to reinvent is called [openid](http://openid.net/).

What you need to do is provide a openid service, and then users can make there own login forms that connect to your open id server.

I have a great example of such a site: http://www.stackoverflow.com that uses google and others as openid service to log in, making there own login form.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is generally referred to as [Single Sign-On](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) (SSO). This can be implemented using a variety of technologies.

The general idea is to separate the *Service Provider (SP)* (also sometimes called *Resource Provider*), which is what provides the actual service the user is going to use, from the *Identity Provider (IdP)*, which is where the user's identity is verified.

The [simplePHP](http://simplesamlphp.org/) library provides implementations for both IdP and SP authenticating layer using a number of SSO standards: SAML, Shibboleth (also SAML-based), OpenID, ...

Note that if you're using a standard, the IdP shouldn't need to be implemented using the same implementation as the one you've chosen for your service. It could be possible to have an IdP implemented in Java using the Shibboleth libraries and use it in conjunction with an SP that uses simplePHP, for example.

Which of these techniques you use will depend on the kind of information your require after authentication, for example if extra attributes are required, and how trust is managed between the IdPs and the SPs.

Typically, a simple OpenID system will be rather straightforward to integrate, from an SP point of view, but it will be quite limited in what it can assert about the user. In contrast, Shibboleth has a number of options to specify which SP can see which user attributes and what IdPs are meant to release or not, but it requires a more substantial infrastructure: this is typically done in a federation, where all the parties exchange a set of metadata configuration that comprises X.509 certificates they use to trust each others' assertions.

Since the authentication will happen outside your administrative boundaries, you can't really control how the users will have authenticated (unless this is part of a more formal agreement, such as in a Shibboleth federation). The OpenID provider could potentially let users authenticate over plain HTTP even if your service requires HTTPS. (This being said, most serious OpenID providers do it securely, and it's up to the user to pick one their trust anyway.)

Never embed the IdP page in your service: make the user go to a their IdP page instead. For an authentication system to be secure (as far as the user is concerned), it is essential that the user be able to see what they're typing their passwords in. By using an iframe, you would effectively hide the real site behind (and logos are easy to grab/forge). (The [StackExchange OpenID provider has some problems in that respect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128733/148833).)